# PHP - ftp_get only works once

Tags: php, ftp, get

I'm connecting to an ftp server that I have no control over, and I'm pretty sure is using something old and outdated due to other issues I've run into.

I'm simply using this code in a loop to get all the files in a directory.

```
ftp_get($this->conn_id, $remote, $local, FTP_ASCII);
```

The first time all goes well, but after that I get this error thrown for each file I try to get: "There is already an active transaction"

I've tried both passive & active, as well as a nonblocking get with no luck. It's the exact same code I use to connect to other FTP servers and get files with no problem.

edit: Oddly enough, closing the connection, sleeping 3 seconds, and creating a new connection between each get yields the same results...

EDIT: Solved. Turns out that despite the errors, the files are still being got. The catch block was just catching the error so I didn't realize it. I'll just ignore that error.

Comment: Your question title refers to get, while your question body refers to put. Which one is right?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ftp_fget` instead and saving the file before trying to get another one.

Comment: Dang. Can you post the entire code snippet your working with so we can see the logic surrounding the call to `ftp_get()`?

Comment: Turns out I'm an idiot. It was actually mysql giving that error because of a stray line of code that was snuck in another method but still being caught in the same block. :(

Comment: It happens to the best of us. I'm not sure how to proceed in SO terms since you answered your own question. Anybody wanna help out here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like "There is already an active transaction" may mean it is still transfering data when you try to use that connection again. Maybe use a sleep() function after puts and gets to give the transaction time to finish and see if that makes a difference. You shouldn't have to do that for php but I would try it just to rule it out as a possible issue.

Comment: I would think several seconds would cover you if thats the problem but it depends how big the file you are transfering is. If its a big file it may need several minutes.